# Java: Why must user satisfy extends constraint?

Tags: java, types, type-theory

Consider this code:

```
public class Enclosing {
    class A<X extends Y, Y> {}

    <U, V> void foo(A<U,V> a) {}
}
```

This gives me an error:

> Type parameter U is not within its bound; should extend V.

However, it should be impossible to call this function unless you can construct an instance of A, so why does the declaration of foo need to ensure that U is within its bound? I understand that you can violate this by passing in `null`, but my intuition would be that soundness still only requires that the "U extends V" constraint be provable when an A is constructed, not when it's used.

So, why is Java requiring that "U extends V" be provable in this declaration? Why is the type system designed this way?

Comment: Are you trying to make a generic class?

Comment: I don't even understand that question. Are you asking if I'm trying to create a type that has type parameters? Yes I am, but that's not very informative

Comment: If you want to know the purpose of this exercise, the short answer is: I'm in general finding ways to push the Java type system to check more interesting properties. This is being used in my research on a new kind of compiler framework

Comment: No, that's very much not what I mean

Comment: So foo is not a method of class A???

Comment: It's not. It can be a method of any class except for A.

Comment: I edited the code to make this complete and unambiguous.

Comment: @JamesKoppel I think that the answer is simply that there is no way of telling that A's generic parameters are the "correct" ones as opposed to foo's. So, what is to win?

Comment: @laune I don't understand that. What does that even mean? This has a very simple interpretation: foo accepts two type parameters, and passes them to A. If you drop the "extends Y" constraint in the declaration, this code works perfectly.

Comment: That's just the point: A is correct, and foo is correct, but there is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand your usage of the word "correct." Can you rephrase that in type theory?

Comment: With all the edit back-and-forth it's hard to know if the code we see is what the OP intended, even after looking at the edit history.  In its current form, aren't the `X` and `Y` in the class declaration completely distinct from the ones in the method declaration? The method is not (in the current incarnation of the question) inside class `A`.  Therefore there's nothing that constrains the method's `X` to extend `Y`.

Comment: *sigh* I edited it again to change the names of the type variables. Yes, these are different type variables with the same name. I don't know why this confuses people. My question stands unanswered: Why is the type system designed this way?

Comment: After that last edit (substituting `U,V` for `X,Y`) I have to agree with the compiler.  There's no guarantee that `U` extends `V`, which would be required in order to declare an `A` parameter.

Comment: "Correct" in the sense of the Java language definition. (More precisely, correct by itself.) foo requires a parameter that is an instantiation of A with two unresttricted generic parameters. But the definition of A requires the X extends Y - you cannot demand to drop the restriction; you can only be more restrictive. It is not necessary to be identical in foo to A's generic parameters.

Comment: Yes, but why is that a requirement? The "U extends V" checking is done when the instance of A is constructed

Comment: For comparison, consider this Haskell:

data A x where
  IsString x => AConstructor :: x -> A x


You can then write a function with signature "foo :: A x -> String" . Here, there is nothing in the signature of foo enforcing that "x" satisfy the "IsString" constraint -- it's enforced when you create an A. So why doesn't Java work like this?

Comment: Quite, but you are saying that you want to drop that restriction for foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although allowing `<U, V> void foo(A<U,V> a)` isn't harmful because you could never construct an instance of `a` if U didn't extend V (although, as you say, you could validly pass `null`), it's not helpful either for the compiler to *not* flag a logical impossibility as soon it sees it.

In the case that you show, the type of the parameter `a` is a logical impossibility. The type is `A` with type parameters U and V where U is not constrained to be a subtype of V. We cannot speak of this type A, since they only type A that exists is the type A where the first type argument *is* constrained to be a subtype of the second type argument.

If the declaration was allowed as you suggest, then this declaration should also be allowed:

```
void foo(A<String,Integer> a);
```

Because in your reasoning, "soundness still only requires that the "String extends Integer" constraint be provable when an A is constructed, not when it's used."

Which could be a way to go about this, but I think most people would prefer the Java compiler to reject impossibilities when it sees them.

Comment: This is very well written and what I was (unsuccessfully and incompetently) trying to say all the time: `class A<...>` and `<...> method` independently define type relationships; if they are made to clash (here: via the foo argument): "which is to win?"

Comment: This is basically the answer I was starting to guess. Or rather, that kind-checking is performed on every declaration of "A<X,Y>" independent of context. If this wasn't the case, I could create a class "CertifiesConstraint<X,Y>"  where just having an instance of CertifiesConstraint<X,Y> is a proof that X extends Y -- and I can provide a method "Y convert(X x)" . Of course, I can do this anyway, but it requires a cast.